# Team Foundation Server: how to delete local files which are not in version control?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am trying to perform a complicated merge between branches of the same solution. We use Team Foundation Server, but I would prefer compare *folders* locally with WinMerge instead of relying on TFS directly to tell me what changed. The problem is, there are a lot of files that are not in source control which pollute the WinMerge folder comparison: bin, obj, static code analysis files, remaining projects that were created locally but discarded and never deleted...

I could delete local folders and force get from source control to clean it, but I'm connected to the source control through a slow VPN and it could take a while; or I could also manually delete whichever files I think are duplicate, but that is too empirical to be exhaustive.

So here's my question: is there any tfs command to clean local folders?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In 2015 **tfpt** has since been deprecated. After downloading the [2015 TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) the new command is:

> **tf reconcile /clean /recursive .**

The ending dot assumes your Developer Command Prompt is sitting at the root directory in your workspace you wish to start from, and /recursive assumes you want to include all subdirectories.

When you run the command it will pop up a preview of all changes it will make, and give you the opportunity to cherry-pick which ones you'd like to keep, if not all.

Note: *pending* files will not be included in the results, which is usually what you want. If you want to remove them as well, you should undo your pending changes first.

Comment: This is great, just open the "**Developer Command Prompt for VS2015**", then move to the solution or project you want reconcile, and then type the **tf** command described above. A nice popup allow to select and unselect the files you want.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the:

`tfpt scorch`

..command for this purpose. the TFPT command line is part of the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)

Answer (score 4):

For Visual Studio 2017, there is no Power Tools but the good news is that most of the features are moved into TFS 2017. Therefore, you can simply use the following without installing any tools.

> tf vc reconcile /clean /recursive .

Answer (score -2):

No, there is no command. As far as the version control doesn't know about the files that are not added to the version control, it cannot delete them.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting without leaving a comment.

Comment: And again. Guys, this question targets TFS 2010, not any later version.